Possitive amplitude subbottom profiller data problem
I only have sub bottom profiles data collected with positive amplitude. Is it possible to produce an envelope section from this sgy data?

Hi Ozhan. Welcome to DSP.SE! You need to provide a lot more details along with what "sgy" means and what kind of envelope you are referring to. Best to detail your own attempts at what you are trying to do and what detail related to signal processing you are stuck on.
